# Como acceder a los mapas de OpenWeatherMap API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

Estoy usando su API y haciendo un proyecto en React donde quiero que muestre algunos mapas, el endpoint según la documentación es el siguiente:

```
https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/{layer}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid={API key}
```

Cuando extraigo los datos y reemplazo quiero acceder a la url para probarla,

```
        const appID = 'XXXXXXXXX';
        const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${ciudad},${pais}&appid=${appID}`;
        
        const zoom = 100;
        
        const respuesta = await fetch(url);
        const resultado = await respuesta.json();
        const x = parseInt(resultado.coord.lon, 10);
        const y = parseInt(resultado.coord.lat, 10);
        console.log(x, y);
        const urlMapa = `https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/${mapa}/${zoom}/${y}/${x}.png?appid=${appID}`;
        console.log(urlMapa);
```

pero tengo el siguiente error cuando ingreso a la urlMapa::

```
{
message: "{x} should be an integer"
}
```

No entiendo si estoy haciendo algo mal o es problema con la API

Comment: Perdón mi ignorancia, no conozco como funciona esta api, pero no cambiaste el orden de `/${x}/${y}` a `/${y}/${x}`?

Comment: Gracias, pero es indistinto igual me sale el error